# Solving a system of ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the simultaneous system of differential equations:
>   $$ \begin{equation}
> x'(t)=y(t) -x(t)/2\\
> y'(t)=x(t)/4-y(t)/2
> \end{equation} $$
>   If $ x(0)=2 $ and $ y(0)=3 $, then what is $ \lim_{t\to\infty}((x(t)+y(t)) $?

Here is what I do:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{1}{4}x-\frac{1}{2}y}{-\frac{1}{2}x+y}=-\frac{1}{2} $$
So $$ y=-\frac{1}{2}x+4 $$ and $$ x(t)+y(t)=\frac{1}{2}x(t)+4 .$$
Now solve for $ x(t) $, we have $$ x(t)=4-\frac{2}{e^t} .$$
Hence $ \lim_{t\to\infty}((x(t)+y(t))=2+4=6 $.

However, there should be another method involving using matrices in the standard way. How to do it via matrices?

The question is from:(14) of https://math.uchicago.edu/~min/GRE/files/week2.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The associated matrix system is
$$\begin{bmatrix}-\frac12&1\\\frac14&-\frac12\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\end{bmatrix}$$
The square matrix has eigenvalues 0 and $-1$, with corresponding eigenvectors $(2,1)^T$ and $(2,-1)^T$. Therefore
$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=a\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix}+be^{-t}\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\end{bmatrix}$$
Solving for the initial conditions yields $2a+2b=2$ and $a-b=3$ or $a=2$ and $b=-1$. In the limit $t\to\infty$, the $b$ term tends to zero, leaving $x(t)+y(t)=2(2+1)=6$.

Comment: Why can we directly get the general solutions after we compute the eigenvectors?

Comment: @Philip That's the standard way to approach it. Specifically, the eigenvectors are linearly independent, so we can use the formula.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix of coefficients is  $$A=\begin {bmatrix}-1/2&1\\1/4&-1/2\end {bmatrix}$$ with eigenvalues of $-1$ and $0$

The eigenvectors are $\begin {pmatrix}2\\-1\end {pmatrix}$ and $\begin {pmatrix}2\\1\end {pmatrix}$

Thus your sollutions are $$\begin {pmatrix}x\\y\end {pmatrix}= c_1e^{-t}   \begin {pmatrix}2\\-1\end {pmatrix}                        
 +c_2\begin {pmatrix}2\\1\end {pmatrix}$$

You  find the constants from initial values.

Comment: Why can we directly get the general solutions after we compute the eigenvectors?

Comment: For each eigenvalue,$\lambda$  and its corresponding eigenvector, $V$  you have a solution $ e^{\lambda t} V$ and the general solution is the linear combination of these solutions.